# How to save data to a text file in a specific format in Matlab?

Tags: file, matlab, text, format

I am a beginner in Matlab and I need help to output my X and Y coordinates in such a format:

```
X-142232Y77639
X-148878Y63979
X-154215Y49757
X-158196Y35097
```

It is a column of `X` and `Y` strings.
Now I have this:

```
fileID = fopen('matrix.txt','a+' );
formatSpec = 'x'%6.4f\n';
fprintf(fileID,'%6.4f\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.4f\n',x, y);
fclose(fileID);
```

In formatSpec I don't know how to add Y? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add additional tokens (`%6.4f` in your case) to your format string:

```
formatSpec = 'X%6.4fY%6.4f\n';
```

Then use that format string in your calls to `fprintf`

```
 fprintf(fileID, formatSpec, x, y);
```

([Documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).)

Comment: Great. Please up-vote and accept the answer if it's what you're looking for, and is complete.